# Return value if parameter is not null

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that will take three parameters any of the parameter may have null value. I have to return other two parameters those values are not null
For example, if I have **a**, **b** and **c** parameter and value of **a** and **b** is null, I have to return **c**. or if value of **b** and **c** are null I have to return **a**.
or if **a** is null return **b and c**.
How can I do that?

```
function returnNotNull= (a, b,c) => {
if (a !== null && b === null && c === null)
    return (a);
```

**Edit**
More clarification:

1. maximum 2 parameters can be null at a time, example: if `a and b` is null then `c` must have value. In that case I want to `return only c`
2. If only 1 parameter is null I want other 2 to return it can be as an array or object
3. If none of the parameter is not null I want to return all of them
4. All three parameters can not be null, so kindly do not consider the case if all parameters are null

Comment: What do you return if there are no nulls?  If only `b` is null?  Etc.

Comment: What do you wanna return when the return value is multi? array or object?

Comment: @ScottSauyet if there is no null I want to return all, or if only b is null i want to return a and c

Comment: @PoppinL if return value is multi i want to return an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of an odd return, sometimes returning a single value, other times returning an array of them, but it seems to meet your needs and is actually flexible in that it handles any number of parameters, not just three:

```js
const returnNotNull = (...args) => {
  const result = args.filter(a => a !== null)
  return result.length == 1 ? result[0] : result
}


console.log(returnNotNull('a', 'b', 'c'))    //~> ['a', 'b', 'c']
console.log(returnNotNull('a', 'b', null))   //~> ['a', 'b']
console.log(returnNotNull('a', null, 'c'))   //~> ['a', 'c']
console.log(returnNotNull('a', null, null))  //~> 'a'
console.log(returnNotNull(null, 'b', 'c'))   //~> ['b', 'c']
console.log(returnNotNull(null, 'b', null))  //~> 'b'
console.log(returnNotNull(null, null, 'c'))  //~> 'c'
console.log(returnNotNull(null, null, null)) //~> []
```

However, if you could *always* return an array, this would be simpler and to my mind quite a bit clearer:

```
const returnNotNull = (...args) => args.filter(a => a !== null)
```

This would simply return an array containing all the non-null values.

Answer (score 0):

why not just something like this? 
If you say it has to return only 1 parameter when the other two are null, right? if all of them are not null, what should happen?

```
returnNotNull = (a, b,c) => {
    return (a || b || c);
}
```

edit : yes so the best is just this then (cf: @sjdm)

```
returnNotNull = (a, b,c) => {
    return ((a != null) ? a : (b != null) ? b : c);
}
```

is there some other situation case that you didn't specify?

Comment: what if the values are 0 but not null, then it still wouldn't return it

Comment: @Crocsx thank you so much for responding, if `let a = 7
let b = 2
let c = 'null'` this function returns me `7` only. What if I want to get 7 and 2 both, may be as an array or an object

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest way I could come up with, using ternary operators. This is quick and easy :)

```
function returnNotNull(a, b, c){
    return ( a !== null ? a : ( b !== null ? b : c));
}

console.log(returnNotNull(null , null , 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction(a,b,c){
 let result  = [];
 for(let argument of arguments){
        //check if argument is not null
  if(argument !== null) result.push(argument);
  
 }
    //if array have only 1 value then return that else return whole array
 return (result.length === 1) ? result[0] : result; 
}
console.log(myFunction(null,1,2));
console.log(myFunction(null,null,2));
console.log(myFunction(null,1,null));
```

#### Second Way

You can convert `arguments` to array using `Array.from` and then use `filter` to get values which are not `null`

```js
function myFunction(a,b,c){
 return Array.from(arguments).filter(argument => argument !==null);
}
console.log(myFunction(null,1,2));
console.log(myFunction(null,null,2));
console.log(myFunction(null,1,null));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function returnNotNull(a, b,c) {

  result = [];

  if(a !== null){ result.push(a); }
  if(b !== null){ result.push(b); }
  if(c !== null){ result.push(c); }

  return result;
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22088371)

Comment: I'm open for clarification on why it does not answer OP at a level clear for OP's level of understanding?

Comment: @glumplum `let a = 7
let b = 2
let c = 'null'

function returnNotNull1(a, b, c) {

    result = [];

    if (a !== null) { result.push(a); }
    if (b !== null) { result.push(b); }
    if (c !== null) { result.push(c); }

    return result;
}
console.log(returnNotNull1(a, b, c))`this will return me` [7,2,"null"]`, if i want to get only [7,2] because c is null I don't want to include it to my return

Comment: @user2019 thanks for the example. Alas i'm still confused, but i guess we don't have to use these comments for enlightening my density. In your example, `c='null'` c is just a string, definitely has a value, and is not the keyword `null`. I assumed from OP's question he meant the keyword `null`, since that is what he used. Oh well...

Comment: I'm not sure what JohanP is talking about.  There are two fixes I would make to this answer, but as far as I can tell, it does answer the original question.  The fixes are first to add some explanation: code-only answers should be extremely rare. And second, this might be better stated with `filter`, which would simplify the code.  My answer starts with `args.filter(...)`, but you could do the same with `[a, b, c].filter(...)`

Comment: @Scott Sauyet Yeah i thought your answer was best, but maybe a bit advanced for OP, based on their difficulty with the logic.

Comment: @glumplum: I like to always push a little.  I figure a little training goes well with an answer.  :-)